# Setup OpenGL 3.2+ on MacOS with GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL but before I can to that I need to setup OpenGL. I've been following [these](http://open.gl/) tutorials and of the suggested support libraries I've chosen GLFW. I managed to download and install GLFW in `/usr/local/` and included `GLFW/glfw3.h` and linked with `libglfw.a`

The problem is that I don't think I'm getting the latest features because some functions aren't declared. `glBindFragDataLocation`, `glGenVertexArrays`, `glBindVertexArray` and `glDrawArrays` aren't declared.

BTW I'm using a 2013 MacBook Air with OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to load the OpenGl Functions for the newer OpenGl Versions. Since this is a lot of work, other people already implemented libraries to do the hard work for you.

Glew is a good one and is mentioned in the tutorial you are following. Try installing and linking with GLFW+Glew and request a core context for OpenGl 3.2 and you should be fine.